# How to get a specific field of a string

Tags: text-processing

I want to get the third column of the last row of the output of `free` command. So far I have this:

```
free | tail -n 1 | (here I need to printf the second column value)
```

How I do that?

Comment: `tail -n 1` gets you the *last* row, not the first. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just `awk`:

`free | awk  'ORS=""; END {print $2}'`

Explanation:

`END` prints just the last line

`{print $2}` prints just the second column

`ORS=""` removes the trailing newline

or, another way with `awk`:

```
free | awk  'END {printf "%s", $2}'
```

Comment: nice nice :) really good

Answer (score 1):

The last line of `free`'s output is `Swap:.....`.  With that knowledge, you can do it with just `awk`:

```
free | awk '/Swap:/ {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ free | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: nice! How do remove the new line of the string?

Comment: `$ free | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs echo -n`